# Group by array and sum variable to see what is the highest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

Take the following array:

```
array = [{"filial"=>"01", "tipo_produto"=>"MR", "total"=>"1492.03"},
         {"filial"=>"01", "tipo_produto"=>"MR", "total"=>"1492.03"},
         {"filial"=>"01", "tipo_produto"=>"PA", "total"=>"1492.03"},
         {"filial"=>"01", "tipo_produto"=>"PA", "total"=>"1492.03"}]
```

I need to group by "tipo_produto" and then sum the "total" of each group to see which group has the highest total summed up. At the end I need to know which group were the highest. Here is what I have so far:

```
array2 = array.group_by { |d| d["tipo_produto"] }
```

Which resulted in the following object:

```
array2 = {"MR"=>[{"filial"=>"01", "tipo_produto"=>"MR", "total"=>"1492.03"}, 
                 {"filial"=>"01", "tipo_produto"=>"MR", "total"=>"1492.03"}], 
          "PA"=>[{"filial"=>"01", "tipo_produto"=>"PA", "total"=>"1492.03"}, 
                 {"filial"=>"01", "tipo_produto"=>"PA", "total"=>"1492.03"}]}
```

What are the next steps? Thank you.

Comment: what is your expected answer

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: what result do you want? can you please give an example

Comment: Any result that gives me what was the highest "tipo_produto". Can be a simple string with "MR" for example, or just the first item in the group by array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution:

```
# your first step
grouped_values = array.group_by {|d| d["tipo_produto"]}
# aggregate by total:
grouped_values.each do |k, v|
  grouped_values[k] = v.inject(0) {|r, i| r + i['total'].to_f }
end
=> {"MR"=>2984.06, "PA"=>2984.06}
# find the highest:
grouped_values.max_by {|_, v| v}
=> ["MR", 2984.06]
```

Comment: Your solution helped me get through, I just had to add one more line to my code to get what I wanted, if you want to edit in your answer so I can accept it: grouped_values.sort_by{|k,v| -v}.first , which resulted in ["PA", 3500.0] ...

Comment: @GustavoGabriel you can use `max_by`:)

Answer (score 1):

You can use max_by after group_by and map :

```
array = [{ 'filial' => '01', 'tipo_produto' => 'MR', 'total' => '1492.03' },
         { 'filial' => '01', 'tipo_produto' => 'MR', 'total' => '1492.03' },
         { 'filial' => '01', 'tipo_produto' => 'PA', 'total' => '1492.03' },
         { 'filial' => '01', 'tipo_produto' => 'PA', 'total' => '1492.05' }]

array2 = array.group_by { |d| d['tipo_produto'] }

types_and_totals = array2.map { |type, products|
  [
    type,
    products.map { |product| product['total'].to_f }.inject(&:+)
  ]
}

p types_and_totals.max_by { |_, total| total }
#=> ["PA", 2984.08]
```

It outputs just the `tipo_produto` and the `total` for the highest sum.